# React-native and react-redux conflict on different version of react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a problem on installing react-redux. I copied and pasted the problem here. Is it reasonable to have 2 versions of react-native at the same time in one project?

react-native says :

> WARN react-native@0.59.4 requires a peer of react@16.8.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

react-redux says  :

> WARN react-redux@7.0.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

by installing 16.8.3, react-redux will look for 16.8.4. on the other side, react-redux does not work with 16.8.3 and required 16.8.4. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason. 22 hours ago react-redux has updated to 7.0.1 and as its documentation says :`The major change for this release is that connect is now implemented using Hooks internally. Because of this, we now require a minimum React version of 16.8.4 or higher.` it requires 16.8.4 at least. So the best solution is now to install react-redux version 6.0.1 by:

```
npm install --save react-redux@6.0.1
```